# Как сверстать страницу html css с помощу python

Tags: python-3.x, css3, django, html5

Нужно красиво вывести логи в сверстаную страницу html, типа как в django.Вопрос - есть ли какая то библиотека, модуль чтоби сделать ето?

P.S. Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список инструментов для шаблонов html и прочего:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

jinja2 популярна например.

Ещё есть вариант сделать страничку например на js движке http://nuxtjs.org и получать данные логов с питона асинхроно в json там..